# How to upload a file from Windows to Linux?

Tags: scp, amazon-ec2

I'm using Windows. I want to upload a file to Amazon server using `putty` from my Windows system.

- How to do this using `scp` or any other command?
- How do I download a file from the Amazon server to my Windows system?

Comment: Use WinSCP or a similar tool.

Comment: You can also use `sftp` on the `command-line`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a full terminal emulator for Windows like Cygwin, MobaXterm, or [BitVise](https://www.bitvise.com/).  Cygwin will let you SSH and SCP from the command line.  MobaXterm has a built in file transfer pane that will follow the command line's working directory.  Like Moba, BitVise offers a terminal and a graphical interface for moving files to and from the remote system.  Following is a picture of the BitVise SFTP interface.

[image: BitVise SFTP interface]

Answer (score 2):

Putty is a terminal client providing you a way to execute commands and view their output on the remote machine. It is not a file transfer client. There is an SCP program in the same family of tools for Windows called [PSCP](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), but it is command line focused for use in a windows console and might not be the easiest place to get started.

Instead I would recommend checking out [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), a graphical client for SCP operations with a two-pane interface for transferring files back and forth that is likely the sort of thing you are looking for. Like all SCP programs it uses the SSH protocol for authentication and over the wire security but is focused on just the file copy operations provided by SCP.

Comment: I am using file zilla client for transfer file but it's too much time consuming. Is pscp faster than fill zilla or winscp?

Comment: @user3676417 What do you mean by time-consuming? Is the interface cumbersome or is the file transfer slow? If the later it is unlikely that either of the options are going to be faster than another, you are likely having bandwidth problems. You should ask about that instead as it seems you already know the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: actually to upload 235 mb file It's getting 9 to 10 hours.I there any way to fast it process?

Comment: @user3676417 Again this has little to do with the software you are using. It sounds like your bandwidth is being throttled somewhere, although since you haven't said how fast your internet should be there is really nothing to do but speculate. You could try a different transport mechanism in case your ISP or someone else is throttling you based on activity type. Start with a generic up/down [speed test](http://speedtest.net) and go from there. Remember most ISP's don't provide as much upload speed as download. [su] might be a better place for a question about how to identify speed issues.

Answer (score 1):

Putty in itself doesn't support file transfers in the way that you want. You would need to download, install and use PSCP and PSFTP (from PuTTY).

There are other clients too such as WinSCP, Filezilla which may suit your needs better.

Comment: I am using file zilla client for transfer file but it's too much time consuming. Is pscp faster than fill zilla or winscp?

Comment: Your best bet would be to enable compression while transferring your data.

Comment: @user3676417 Please don't keep commenting on answers with separate questions. You asked the same thing on my answer. If we have not answered the question you asked you can request clarification, but you seem to have a question unrelated to your original question or either of our answers. If you need an answer about filezilla being slow, you can ask that as a separate question but it is not a Unix&Linux question and should be asked on [su].